# Store a Selected Items From a Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listitem

I can't seem to get my application to store the selected items from a listbox.

Each time I run the code and debug it selects the first item in the list as the selected item from the listbox even if it is not selected and stores this item but for the actual items that have been selected they are ignored. This even happens if I set all properties of the listitems to Selected="false" in the ASP tag.

I have the same code used for a checkboxlist and it works fine I cannot see why this is not working?

I have not included the Answers class as it just gets and sets the properties.

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbQuestion3" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="7">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" >Dublin</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Cork</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Waterford</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Limerick</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" >Carlow</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" >Galway</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" >Kilkenny</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnQuestion4" runat="server" Text="Next Question" OnClick="btnQuestion4_Click"/>
```

C# code

```
protected void btnQuestion4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Answers question3;

            List<Answers> answers = new List<Answers>();

            foreach (ListItem item in lbQuestion3.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected == true)
                {
                    question3 = new Answers(item.Text, Convert.ToInt32(item.Value), 0);

                    answers.Add(question3);
                }


            Session["ssAnswerQ3"] = answers;

            Response.Redirect("Question4.aspx");
        }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["ssAnswerQ3"] != null)
            {
                List<Answers> previousAnswers = new List<Answers>();

                previousAnswers = (List<Answers>)Session["ssAnswerQ3"];

                foreach (ListItem item in lbQuestion3.Items)
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in previousAnswers)
                    {
                        if (item2.Answer == item.Text)
                        {
                            item.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

John

Comment: Could you show me page load event?

Comment: @RashminJaviya Page Load Event Added To main question Thanks.